# What is the difference between Agathon Matthew 7:17 and Kalon in Matthew 7:19?

Tags: matthew

Is there any difference in the meaning of the two Greek terms or their meanings overlap in general?

Matthew 7:17  (NASB)

> 17 "So every good tree bears **good** fruit, but the bad tree bears
>   bad fruit."

Matthew 7:17 1881 (WHNU)

> 17 ουτως παν δενδρον **αγαθον** καρπους καλους ποιει το δε σαπρον
>   δενδρον καρπους πονηρους ποιει

Matthew 7:19  (NASB)

> 19 "Every tree that does not bear **good** fruit is cut down and
>   thrown into the fire."

ΜΑΤΘΑΙΟΝ 7:19 1881 Westcott-Hort New Testament (WHNU)

> 19 παν δενδρον μη ποιουν καρπον **καλον** εκκοπτεται και εις πυρ
>   βαλλεται

Comment: You could focus the question further by just concentrating on v17 which has both agathos and kalos in the same verse and sentence.  In any case, the two words have greatly overlapping meanings.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Mac's Musings. I have edited the question.

Comment: The two words occur in the same sentence in v17

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What is the difference between Agathon Matthew 7:17 and Kalon in Matthew  7:19?**

**Καλον:**

Καλὸν=kalon: and it means, "good, fine, better or excellent"  and it is used to denote that which is  of fine  or excellent quality. A key word search on Bible Gateway for WHNU revealed 50 occurrences of of the word "καλον" (kalon). Some examples  of the uses below.

Matthew 7:19 (NRSV)

> 19 "Every tree that does not bear **good** fruit is cut down and
>   thrown into the fire."

Matthew 7:19 WHNU

> "παν δενδρον μη ποιουν καρπον **καλον** εκκοπτεται και εις πυρ
>   βαλλεται"

Mark 9:43 (NRSV)

> 43 "If your hand causes you to stumble, cut it off; it is **better** for
>   you to enter life maimed than to have two hands and to go to hell, to
>   the unquenchable fire."

ΚΑΤΑ ΜΑΡΚΟΝ 9:43 1881 (WHNU)

> "και εαν σκανδαλιση σε η χειρ σου αποκοψον αυτην **καλον** εστιν σε
>   κυλλον εισελθειν εις την ζωην η τας δυο χειρας εχοντα απελθειν εις την
>   γεενναν εις το πυρ το ασβεστον"

John 2:10  (NRSV)

> 10 "And said to him, “Everyone serves the **good** wine first, and then
>   the inferior wine after the guests have become drunk. But you have
>   kept the good wine until now.”

ΚΑΤΑ ΙΩΑΝΝΗΝ 2:10 1881 (WHNU)

> "και λεγει αυτω πας ανθρωπος πρωτον τον **καλον** οινον τιθησιν και
>   οταν μεθυσθωσιν τον ελασσω συ τετηρηκας τον καλον οινον εως αρτι"

James 4:17  (NRSV)

> 17 "Anyone, then, who knows the **right** thing to do and fails to do
>   it, commits sin."

ΙΑΚΩΒΟΥ 4:17 1881  (WHNU)

> 17 "ειδοτι ουν **καλον** ποιειν και μη ποιουντι αμαρτια αυτω εστιν"

**Agathon:**

Similar to  καλον,  but used in the sense of being  good , as in  excellent spirituality , morality. Jesus although having moral excellence refused to accept the title "Good" and his reply (Mark 10:18 read below) indicated that only God is **"good"** in the absolute sense.

A derivative of "agathos " is "agathosini " translated into "goodness" and is a  fruit of God's spirit, (Galatians 5:22) hence it is not a quality that any person has in the absolute sense, but it is a quality which has to be cultivated.

Some examples of the uses of the word "Agathon" in the scriptures below . A key word search revealed ten occurrences in WHNU New Testament- BibleGateway

Matthew 7:11  (NASB)

> 11 "If you then, being evil, know how to give **good** gifts to your
>   children, how much more will your Father who is in heaven give what is
>   **good** to those who ask Him!"

ΜΑΤΘΑΙΟΝ 7:11 1881 (WHNU)

> 11 ει ουν υμεις πονηροι οντες οιδατε δοματα αγαθα διδοναι τοις τεκνοις
>   υμων ποσω μαλλον ο πατηρ υμων ο εν τοις ουρανοις δωσει **αγαθα** τοις
>   αιτουσιν αυτον

Matthew 7:17 (NASB)

> 17 So every **good** tree bears good fruit, but the bad tree bears bad
>   fruit.

Matthew 7:17 1881 (WHNU)

> 17 ουτως παν δενδρον **αγαθον** καρπους καλους ποιει το δε σαπρον
>   δενδρον καρπους πονηρους ποιει

Matthew 12:35 New (NRSV)

> 35 "The good person brings **good** things out of a good treasure, and the
>   evil person brings evil things out of an evil treasure."

ΚΑΤΑ ΜΑΤΘΑΙΟΝ 12:35 1881 (WHNU)

> 35 "ο αγαθος ανθρωπος εκ του **αγαθου** θησαυρου εκβαλλει αγαθα και ο
>   πονηρος ανθρωπος εκ του πονηρου θησαυρου εκβαλλει πονηρα"

Mark 10:17-18 Amplified Bible (AMP)

> 17 "As He was leaving on His journey, a man ran up and knelt before
>   Him and asked Him, “Good Teacher [You who are essentially good and
>   morally perfect], what shall I do to inherit eternal life [that is,
>   eternal salvation in the Messiah’s kingdom]?” 18 "Jesus said to him,
>   “Why do you call Me **good?** No one is [essentially] **good** [by nature]
>   except God alone."

ΚΑΤΑ ΜΑΡΚΟΝ 10:18 1881  (WHNU)

> 18 "ο δε ιησους ειπεν αυτω τι με λεγεις **αγαθον** ουδεις **αγαθος** ει μη εις
>   ο θεος"

Acts 11:24  (NASB)

> 24 "For he was a **good** man, and full of the Holy Spirit and of faith.
>   And considerable [a]numbers were [b]brought to the Lord."

Acts 11:24 1881  (WHNU)

> 24 "οτι ην ανηρ **αγαθος** και πληρης πνευματος αγιου και πιστεως και
>   προσετεθη οχλος ικανος τω κυριω"

**Conclusion:**

English translations translate both words as "good" the meaning of the words overlap as follows. (To the best of my knowledge there is no English  equivalent word for "Agathon")

"Kαλον" is as  used in the scriptures to  describe what is excellent, beautiful, exquisite, for example  "as fine fruit", "good fruit," "excellent wine," "good shepherd" that which gives  delight and pleasure to the eyes and the heart.

"Agathos" also translated "good" by many translations, it used to denotes spiritual and moral excellence ,{ An Oxford Dictionary definition of," Good" - is what is  considered to be right according to moral standards or religious beliefs. eg. the conflict between good and evil.}